# Eclipse Indigo missing POM Editor preferences

Tags: eclipse, tabs, pom.xml

I use eclipse Indigo. I installed from market place (*Help -> MarketPlace...*) Maven Integration for Eclipse. Everything is ok, but pom editor has only a few tabs (Overview, Depedencies, Depedency Hierarchy, Effective POM, pom.xml).

I went to *Window->Preferences->Maven* but there are not any POM Editor preferences.
(Archetypes, Discovery, Installations, Templates, User Interface, User Settings)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to be removed since the m2eclipse moved to the eclipse project.

> We removed these tabs. They never worked properly and/or did not bring
>   enough value to justify code maintenance overhead, so we decided to
>   concentrate our efforts on tabs that are actually used and useful make
>   work with pom.xml signifantly easier.

http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-users/msg00973.html