# Eclipse luna don't show some tabs in form-based POM

Tags: pom.xml, m2eclipse, eclipse-luna

I have installed Eclipse Luna and the plugin "m2eclipse" (last update). I can't see some tabs in form-based POM explorer. In maven options I haven't found nothing. Some suggestion?

I can see only this tabs:

- overview
- dependencies
- dependency hierarchies
- effective pom
- pom.xml

Where is the more other tabs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact there is only these 5 tabs now. You can find more information [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7239441/1947164) or directly on this [mailing list](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-users/msg00973.html).

The main explanation is other tabs were not useful.